# Menu item text color programatically change not working?

Tags: android

hi friends i would like to change menu item text color i have tried this

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuItem settingsMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.newfield);
SpannableString s = new SpannableString(settingsMenuItem.getTitle());
s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#00FFBB")), 0, s.length(), 0);
settingsMenuItem.setTitle(s);
return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

 @Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.feedbackaddnew, menu);

    return true;
}
```

but color is not changing

Comment: add this line in your theme <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/your_color</item>

Comment: Hi sowmya, you can check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can change menu text color via style

Try This one:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">    
<item name="actionMenuTextColor">@color/text_color</item>
<item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.feedbackaddnew, menu);
    MenuItem settingsMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.newfield);
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(settingsMenuItem.getTitle());
    s.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.parseColor("#00FFBB")), 0, s.length(), 0);
    settingsMenuItem.setTitle(s);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Just in the `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method.

Comment: Thanks will try your post  and share

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, when onPrepareOptionsMenu calls if we try to update it's not updating may be because the view is not rendered completely, So I added 100 ms delay and updated its working fine.

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            View view = findViewById(R.id. newfield);

            // Cast to a TextView instance if the menu item was found
            if (view != null && view instanceof TextView) {
                ((TextView) view).setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00FFBB"));
            }
        }
    }, 100);

    return true;
}
```

Note:

> We are doing in post delay so it will before that if we close the app
>   menu will be null it will crash, So better try to revoke the runnable
>   before activity destroy.

Comment: Thanks i didn't use TextView in menu

Comment: You don't use, but MenuItem is TextView you can change the properties like this.

Comment: Just give your id in that and check.